# Prevent screen reader from reading link content

Tags: vue.js, accessibility, vue-router, tailwind-css, wcag2.0

i'am trying making my web application (Vue + Tailwind) more accessible but i'am having lot of problems undestanding how to use all the aria- attributes.

In this case i have something like this

```
< div v-for="_class in classes" :key="_class.id">

      < router-link
        :to="`/user/classes/${_class.id}`"
         :aria-labelledby="_class.id"
      >

        < p class="hidden" :id="_class.id">
          Select class {{ _class.name }} , {{ _class.code }} ,
          {{ _class.type.replace("_", "") }}
        < /p>

          < div
          class="py-8 px-10 bg-white text-gray-800 rounded-xl w-full sm:w-350 md:w-                   full shadow-lg h-full"
        >
          ....content of the div
```

I'd like that when the link is focused only the description of < p> is read but screen reader keeps on adding the word "link" at the end of the description because of the router-link focus,how can i disable this? And second and more important, when a link is pressed and navigation leads to the following page, screen readers reads all of the content of inner div inside the router-link. Can someone help me understand how to disable this behaviuor?

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions:

1. How to prevent the screen reader from saying "link".

**Answer:** You don't, or rather, you **shouldn't**.  Hearing "link" is telling the screen reader user that you have a link so they know what the expected behavior will be when they select it.  Are you saying the user shouldn't know what type of object they're on?  You can do that with `role="presentation"` but if you do that on a link, you will create a [WCAG 4.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#name-role-value) issue.

2. How to prevent all content from being read.

**Answer:**  That's a screen reader setting.  When a page loads, the screen reader user has the option to have the entire page read by default or to just read the element that has focus.  It's purely a user decision and you should not try to force anything otherwise.

However, you also said the *"screen reader reads all of the content of inner div inside the router-link"*.  I'm not sure what a "router link" is, I'm not a vue or tailwind user, but with normal links, `<a>`, the link that launched the navigation should not be read *after* the user has navigated to the new location.  Are you saying your link text is announced after navigating away from it?

Comment: Yes, i mean that after the router link is pressed, navigation leads correctly to the new page but screen readers announce the text elements inside the inner div of the router link and this is really annoying, maybe i should try to force focus on some element on the new page to prevent this